# Delaunay triangulation for 3D - a list of connections

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a problem with Delaunay triangulation in 3D. I know that the function `DelaunayTriangulation[vector]` does not work in case of three-dimensional vectors.  But I need no graphics but connections between points. For instance, in 2D case I can get following list of connections:

```
{{1, {64, 10, 22, 51, 55, 15, 41}}, {2, {71, 76, 50, 61, 80, 95}}, {3, {101, 94, 78, 100, 7, 66}}, {4, {102, 99, 57, 43, 64, 56}}, ...}
```

Is it possible to get a similar list for 3D points? At this moment, I have only such a picture thanks to function `DelaunayMesh`. Maybe there is a possibility to get a list of connections?

[image: Delaunay mesh]
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by `connections`? Maybe you mean the vertex-vertex adjacency lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? In order to use it, you have to install Szabolcs' package [`"IGraphM`"](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) first.

```
vector = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
M = DelaunayMesh[vector];

Needs["IGraphM`"]
IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, 0]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Connections, for me, means vertex-vertex adjacency lists. I have tried use these commands but I got a list which has greater numbers than the total number of vertex, for instance 
`{261, 331, 431, 438}`
I have only 100 points (but you have created 2-dimensional vector, I need the 3-dimensional one), so probably it is not a good solution.

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault. Please see my edit.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the property `"VertexVertexConnectivity"` :

Using `M` from Henrik's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
vector = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
M = DelaunayMesh[vector];

vvc = M["VertexVertexConnectivity"]
Short @ %
```

> {{24,89,18,91,2},{24,1,91,21,87},{77,86,71,48,59},<<94>>,{36,58,34,21,85},{18,86,77,96,84},{6,61,38,60,40}}

This  is the same as Henrik's result up to ordering of sublists:

```
Sort /@ vvc == Sort /@ IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, 0]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> True